Error when setting up eosio.system contract - env.preactivate_feature unresolveable
Setting up a local eosio network using docker and facing an issue while setting the contract for eosio.system and eosio.bios.
Eosio setup
eosio : v2.1.0
eosio.cdt: v1.7.0
eosio.contracts: v1.9.0

Errors
root@eosio-node1:/eosio.contracts# cleos set contract eosio ./build/contracts/eosio.system/ -p eosio
Reading WASM from /eosio.contracts/build/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.wasm...
Publishing contract...
Error 3070003: Serialization Error Processing WASM
Error Details:
env.preactivate_feature unresolveable
pending console output:

cleos set contract eosio.bios ./build/contracts/eosio.bios/
Reading WASM from /eosio.contracts/build/contracts/eosio.bios/eosio.bios.wasm...
Publishing contract...
Error 3070003: Serialization Error Processing WASM
Error Details:
env.set_proposed_producers_ex unresolveable
pending console output:

How can this be rectified??
